# How do I gracefully kill managed applications on shutdown?

Tags: c#, .net, shutdown

I am creating a C# app that handles Excel applications.

The excel file I am loading are preloaded (as it takes a while to load it due to the file's girth) and then shown when requested by the user.

However, when the user shuts down Windows, Windows sends Session query ended messages to the hidden excel app, forcing a visible "Would you like to save changes to '(EXCEL FILE)'?".

How do I override this behavior and gracefully kill off the excel file?

I've looked into suppressing the save prompt via VBA, but Session Ended messages do not execute this code.

Additionally, I've looked into killing the process by handling my own C# app's Session Query End message, but this is unreliable as it is a race (what app gets the message first, my C# or my hidden excel file)

**Edit:**
By gracefully kill, I mean just kill the process off without prompting the user. I know how to do this when the user chooses to exit my program, I just don't know when to call this routine.

**Edit2:**
I keep track of instances of Excel in memory using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Comment: What do you mean by 'gracefully killing' the application? Force close without save but not show the dialogue? Save without user intervention?

Comment: @DMan I mean just kill off the application process without saving. I do this normally when the user closes my app, but Windows shut down is interfering with this

Comment: Surely the app will be killed when Windows shuts down though?

Comment: Can you please clarify a "C# app that handles Excel applications"?  What are you exactly doing?

Comment: @BaliC Excel behaves differently when closed by `WM_QueryEndSession` then closed via process termination (the "Would you like to save?" prompt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without showing your code it's difficult to tell what you have, however, here is a snippet from my code which works in a similar situation (I think) without a prompt:

```
Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
xl.Visible = false;
xl.DisplayAlerts = false;

//do something

xl.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl);
xl = null;
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: I've used `xl.DisplayAlerts` before, I remember it suppressing some prompts, but not all.  It's certainly worth a try though.  I've been seeing a lot of people use `Workbook.Saved = true;` as well, but I'm not sure if that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens `Workbook.Saved = true;` was the ticket here. I was overthinking trying to intercept Windows shutdown messages being sent to excel